# Custom post-type working except for Selecting page-parent

Tags: customization, page-attributes

I created a custom post type in functions.php with these values (amongst others):

```
'hierarchical'        => true,
'supports'            => array( 'title', 'thumbnail', 'revisions', 'page-attributes'),
'capability_type'     => 'page',
```

I understood this should be the bits needed to get *page attributes* to offer *parent page* as a dropdown to make it a child of another page, however all that shows in *page attributes* is *Order* with a number box. Have I missed something to get this working? I assume also that if this was working my *custom content-type page* would be available to choose as the *homepage* in *Settings/Reading* ?

Comment: Yes, these arguments should be all that you need to have the ability to select a parent CPT. Did you change anything after you initially registered the CPT? WP is bad about settings changes after a CPT is registered once, so you might try `unregister_post_type('slug')` right above your call to `register_post_type('slug')` and see if that fixes things.

Comment: Just for sanity have you resaved permalinks backend?

Comment: Hi both - just tried both those things, no joy. I tried unregister_post_type on its own first to check that worked, the post_type vanished, the re-registered it, and updated permalinks - still doesn't offer page parent in properties. For one of these post-types I could get round the parent issue, but I need to be able to select one of them as homepage.